# Do i need to send device registration token to fcm console?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i've a question, I'm using firebase cloud message to push notification to android, do i need to send device registration token to fcm console everytime the new token generated or will the token in fcm console update itself? Does Fcm console have token management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase console has no built-in token management capability. If you want to send a message to a specific token through the Firebase console, you will have to copy/paste it from somewhere else.

Realistically you will only do this during development, for example to test of delivery to your test device works. Once you reach production, you'll want a more scalable way of sending messages to devices, either by sending to topics through the console, or by sending to specific tokens through you own token database and then calling the FCM API for sending messages.

Comment: in case of new token generated, do i need to let firebase know that new token has been generated, or firebase automatically know?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're doing. But if you've configured the Firebase console to send to a specific token at a specific time, it will send to that token at the configured time. It won't know anything about a new token, which that's not what you've configured it with.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is it still possible to send a message to a specific token from the console? I can't find the option anywhere.

Comment: I think that's considered "Sending a test message" in the Firebase console these days @MadMac